# Share on Facebook does not show thumbnail images

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have the same PHP application on a development server and on a live server.

We have a "Share on Facebook" button that,

- On the development server shows the thumbnail images correctly and allows the user to select between them
- On the live server, it does NOT show the thumbnail images at all.

The URLs on top of the window that appears shows the following:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.servera.com%2Fdirectory%2F696%2Ftest33&t=test33%20by%20Org1%20%20on%20This%20Site

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.serverb.com%2Fbeta%2Fdirectory%2F638%2FMEtest6&t=test6%20by%20Ins%20on%20This%20Site
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I diagnose this better?

Comment: Maybe the servers are configured differently?

Comment: The thumbnails are generated by the FB servers, which make an HTTP request for the page from the outside. Is the page you're sharing publicly accessible?

Comment: @Piskvor - its able to get the text data fine, not the images though...

Comment: @faileN - yes, they are configured differently, but what aspect of it would be causing it? something in .htaccess for image caching?

Comment: @Piskvor - *both* are able to get the text data fine, the latter is not able to get the images though...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://fbmhell.com/2010/10/breaking-facebook-share-cache

here is the direct link:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/